# On tmux, what is the difference between "bind" and "bind-key"?

Tags: tmux

On .tmux.conf, what is the difference between "bind" and "bind-key"?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

"bind" is an alias for "bind-key", they have the same effect.
Also you can shorten commands as long as there is only one command that starts with the letters you write, so for instance "bind-k" or "bin" would work as well.

From the man page:

```
bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]
                    (alias: bind)

(...)

 Most commands have a shorter form, known as an alias.  For new-session,
 this is new:

       $ tmux new vi

 Alternatively, the shortest unambiguous form of a command is accepted.
```